# Invariants of $\mathbb{Z}[x, x^{-1}, y, y^{-1}]$ under actions of finite subgroups in $\text{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, group-actions, invariant-theory

Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[x, x^{-1}, y, y^{-1}]$. How can one find the ring of invariants $A^G$ for finite subgroups $G \subset \text{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$?

The action of a matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}
$$
is described by $x \mapsto x^a y^c$ and $y \mapsto x^b y^d$.

For example, let $G \cong D_3$, where the isomorphism is given by
\begin{align*}
s & \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \\
r & \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
act on $A$.

Is there some nice software to solve such problems?

EDIT: Invariant rings, produced by reflection groups, can be polynomial rings. Is there an algorithm for finding the generators of such polynomial rings (for two and more dimensions)?

Comment: what is the action?

Comment: Up to conjugation, there are finitely many finite subgroups in $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}$ (the largest one should have 12 elements or something like that).

Comment: I believe the list is the following: The dihedral groups of order $12$, order $8$, order $6$ in two ways (either the $1$-eigenspaces are a basis or the $-1$-eigenspaces are) and order $4$ in two ways (either the eigenspaces are an integer basis or they span an index two sublattice). The cyclic groups of orders $6$, $3$ and $4$. The group of order $2$ in three ways: By $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} -1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$, $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ and $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. And the trivial group.

Comment: Some of these cases have nice concise answers, and I could work out any of them if I really needed to, but every time that I start working on a complete answer it turns into a long list of ad hoc tricks, which is why I haven't responded to this. Hoping someone can give a clean approach.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, thank you for your answer! I have already found these subgroups, and I know that dihedral groups will produce nice polynomial rings. I also have found the candidates for these rings using "long staring" method.
However, I am still interested if there is a nice algorithm for finding the generators of the polynomial (invariant) rings

Comment: I'm hoping someone else will answer the question about software. Be warned about the statement that dihedral groups have nice invariants: $S_3$ acting on so that the 1-eigenspaces span the lattice is polynomial, but $S_3$ acting so that the $-1$-eigenspaces span is not!